# How to send enum type to Invoke (delegate) Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, enums, delegates

I've a function to modify a PictureBox, so I need to use a delegate. My function needs an int in order to do its job, and I've created an enum in order to define the values it can have.

However, when I'm invoking it, there's a problem because it **cannot convert from my enum to object**, in order to send it the the function.

How can I face it?

My function:

```
System::Void modifyButtonPicture(int estado)
```

The enum:

```
enum BUTTON_STATE : int { PB_STOP = 0, PB_PLAY = 1 };
```

Delegate:

```
delegate void SetTextDelegatePlayButton(int estado);
```

Invoke:

```
Invoke(gcnew SetTextDelegatePlayButton(this, &Form1:: modifyButtonPicture), PB_PLAY);
```

The error message (translated):

```
error C2664: 'System::Object ^System::Windows::Forms::Control::Invoke(System::Delegate ^,...cli::array<Type> ^)' : cannot convert 2nd parameter from 'BUTTON_STATE' to 'System::Object ^'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented by MSDN [Control::Invoke Method (Delegate, array)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx) the Invoke method accepts these parameters:

> **method**
>   Type: System::Delegate
>   A delegate to a method that takes parameters of the same number and type that >are contained in the args parameter.
>   **args**
>   Type: array
>   An array of objects to pass as arguments to the specified method. This parameter can be nullptr if the method takes no arguments.

And in your call, your passing an int as the second parameter (the `PB_PLAY`).

So you need to cast your enum to an System::Object array:

```
int play = (int)PB_PLAY;
array<Object^>^myEnumArray = {play};
Invoke(gcnew SetTextDelegatePlayButton(this, &Form1:: modifyButtonPicture), myEnumArray);
```

Comment: The line `array<Object^>^myEnumArray = {PB_PLAY};` gives the same error as before, that it cannot be casted from my enum type to object =(